# C++ remove duplicate elements from two vectors

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates

I have two vectors, `std::vector<double> xvec` and `std::vector<double> yvec`, each has millions of elements and same size. But the combination of xvec[i] and yvec[i] is used to define a unique object. For example

```
xvec = {1.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,2.0}
yvec = {5.0,1.0,1.5,2.0,1.0}
```

Then 2.0_1.0 combination is the duplicated element, which should be removed from the both x and y vectors.

I want to the xvec and yvec be returned after removing the duplicate elements. Followed the example, the returned xvec and yvec should be

```
xvec = {1.0,2.0,2.0,3.0}
yvec = {5.0,1.0,1.5,2.0}
```

I know how to do such task for a single vector, using sort and unique functions. But anyone can offer me some idea to finish this algorithm?

Comment: Have you thought about using a map or a set or other kind of container that does not allow duplicate values? If you want to implement the "no duplication" thing yourself, you can always use a linked list and only insert values that are not already in it....by using the binary search algorithm function. Here is a great article on how to insert nodes into a list that is already sorted...http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/

Comment: Thanks. I will try c++ map and the sorted unique functions.

Comment: Zip the vectors into a set of pairs. No need to sort explicitly.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question but if you want all the items in the first one that aren't duplicates AND all the items in the second one that aren't duplicates, why can't you just take the set difference of xvec and yvec + the set difference of yvec and xvec?

Answer (score 0):

I would see three possibilities:

## Solution 1

Implement `std::sort` and `std::unique` yourself for the given problem. `std::unique` is easy to implement but I don't want to implement a sort algorithm now. So I will not show you an example for that.

## Solution 2

Implement your own `RandomAccessIterator` and `ForwardIterator` and use `std::sort` and `std::unique`.

## Solution 3

Iterate through the values and use a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` to check if the current values already exists.

```
std::vector<double> xvec = {...};
std::vector<double> yvec = {...};

std::set<std::tuple<double,double> > set;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < xvec.size();) {
    if (set.emplace(xvec[i], yvec[i]).second) {
        i++;
    } else {
        xvec.erase(xvec.begin() + i);
        yvec.erase(yvec.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not complied for std::set<std::tuple<double,double> > set; even though I already #include <set> and #include <tuple>, do you know why is that? Thanks.

Comment: I tested it on my pc and it seems to work for me. What is the error message? `std::tuple` and `std::set::emplace` is only available with *C++11*, maybe you haven't enabled it? I'm not sure but If you are using `using std::set;` or `using namespace std;`, the variable name `set` maybe could cause an error.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the other answer, also needs c++11, it looks like in my computer the c++11 is not working.

Comment: Maybe you can use `std::pair` instead of `std::tuple` and `std::set::insert` instead of `std::set::emplace`. I think then it should work without *C++11*.

Comment: Thanks. I make those modifications, also not work. it says this sentence has some error "if (set.emplace(xvec[i], yvec[i]).second) "

Comment: The error infor is:  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:1324: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’, maybe it is due to the g++ compiler in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by storing your `xvec` and `yvec` as a vector of pairs i.e. `std::vector<std::pair<double,double> > vec`. This would allow you to easily use both `std::sort` and `std::unique` to achieve what you are describing. I have included some code below that demonstrates this.

**Note:** The code below is a bit verbose but will demonstrates a working solution by printing each element before and after the de-duplication has occured. The code should be compiled with the flag `--std=c++11`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // Vector of pairs with duplicates.
    std::vector<std::pair<double,double> > vec = {{1,1},{1,3},{1,1},{2,4},{5,1}};

    std::cout << "Before:\n";
    // Prints x - values
    std::cout << "x:";
    for (auto i : vec)
    {
        std::cout << i.first << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\ny:";

    // Prints y - values
    for (auto i : vec)
    {
        std::cout << i.second << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\nAfter:\n";

    // The magic happens here :)
    std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    auto last = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase(last, vec.end());

    std::cout << "x:";
    // Prints x - values
    for (auto i : vec)
    {
        std::cout << i.first << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\ny:";
    // Prints y - values
    for (auto i : vec)
    {
        std::cout << i.second << "\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But you mentioned this code is complied with the flag -- std=c++11, I do not know the Makefile. Do you have simpler way to compile this code?

Comment: This code makes use of syntax only available after c++11 this means that you need to compile specifying this. An example of how you could do this would be using the command line and typing something along the lines of `g++ myfile.cpp -o myfile.exe --std=c++11` this does away with the need to use a makefile

Comment: I tried g++ remove_test.C -o remove_test.exe --std=c++11, there is such an error:  cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-fDstd=c++11". Probably my g++ is out of date. Thanks.

Comment: try `g++ --version` if it prints a version greater than 4.4 then it should be compatible??

Comment: Yes. I tried. It shows:                                                                                            g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc. So it is indeed out of date.

Comment: maybe try and change the extension of your file to `.cpp` instead of `.C` ??

Comment: still does not work. I will ask the computer manager to upgrade the g++ compiler since I do not have root permission.

Comment: Your compiler is not out of date g++ version 4.4.7 is capable of this syntax. Perhaps it was a typo when you entered it into the command line??

Comment: I checked many times, there is no typo in the command line. I will ask the computer manager to check it. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanielBrough @HuanianZhang `--std=c++11` is a wrong argument. You have to write `-std=c++11` (only one `-`).

Comment: @JojOatXGME I tried -std=c++11, still does not work. The same error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

Comment: @HuanianZhang You can try `-std=c++0x` too. It was the argument to enable available C++11 features before the standard of C++11 was finished.